# Reflect TextView in Widget

Tags: android

On the main screen of my app, there is a TextView that displays the number of entries for the month. This number only changes when you add/delete an item from an SQLiteDB.

What I want to do is always reflect that number in my widget. Given that I only want to update it when the user adds/deletes an item, what's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user either adds or removes an item, you can either call the `onUpdate` method of your widget directly, or send a new broadcast that would trigger your widget update.  Then in `onUpdate` you read the count from your DB and populate your widget UI.

**EDIT**

This code allows you to update your widgets from an `Activity`

```
private void updateAllWidgets(){
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, MyWidget.class));
    if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
        new MyWidget().onUpdate(this, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how to call the onUpdate. In my main activity, I've done: private AppWidget mAppWidget; mAppWidget.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, mValue);  I added mValue to pass the number but I'm not sure what to set for context, appWidgetManager and appWidgetIds

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a method that updates the `TextView` and then call this method from the code that adds/deletes items.

There isn't a clean way to tell the `TextView` to always change when the db content changes; it's best to locate the points in your code where such changes can occur and handle them accordingly.

Note that changes to your db that occur in other activities can be handled by calling your update method in the `onResume` method of the activity that contains the `TextView`.